# str_replace for a string with breaklines

Tags: php

Im stuck on a very silly piece of code. 
Hope one can help:

I would like to remove the blank spaces from the string:

"ffdf

gfdf

hffd"

and replace by '/'

Till now, I have tried various thing, lst to be

```
str_replace('\n','/','ffdf
gfdf
hffd')
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: You need to use double quotes around `"\n"` or PHP will not interpret the escape character, and instead see a literal backslash-n.

Comment: Read the [PHP manual on strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for the difference in quoting.

Answer (score 2):

You should use "\n". (double apostrophes.) (Singles ones doesn't understand the \ escapes.)

Like this:

```
 str_replace("\n",'/','ffdf
gfdf
hffd')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str_replace("\n\r",'/','Your String Here')
```

or

```
str_replace("\n\r",'/','Your String Here')
```

or

```
str_replace("\r",'/','Your String Here')
```

\n between `" "` Like `"\n"`
between `' '` Not Working...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, blank spaces are simply . So, you should use:

```
str_replace(" ", "/", $text);
```